# Prevent User to fill in a specified value into a cell before another cell is filled

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, validation

Since I am not that well versed in Excel I have stumbled upon the following Problem:

I have the two cells:
**A1 and B1**

I want **A1 not to be able to be filled with the value "1" before B2 is filled.** (User needs to fill in B1 before filling in the value "1" to A1 while still being able to enter other values with out problems)

I have seen a lot of ways to tackle similar problems with the validations and the ISBLANK function but non of them seem to quite hit the mark.
Thanks for any help in advance.
Best Regards,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Data Validation** to get the result, please follow these steps:

1. Select **A1**- go to **Data**- **Data Validation**- **Custom**- and enter the formula:

   =AND(B1<>0,A1<>1)

[image]

2. Go to **Error Alert** and enter the **Title** and **Error message** you need- and then you will get the result you need:

[image]